# How to Enable Global Settings Changes in jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, keyboard-shortcuts, jkey

I have a jQuery plugin ( https://github.com/OscarGodson/jKey ) and some users are needing localization support. My instinctive thought would be to have another param in the plugin to allow localization like:

```
$(window).jkey('?',callback,{'?':223})
```

Or save it to a var like

```
var localization = {'?':223,'a':224,'b':225,'c':226}
$(window).jkey('?',callback,localization)
```

But this is sort of a pain in the ass as most users would want to localize all of their code not just one snippet. So, is there a way to set a global jQuery setting? For example, be able to go like

```
$.jkey({localization:{'?':223}})
```

And then on our all calls to `$().jkey()` would use that?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement what you describe in this way:

```
(function ($) {

    var defaults = {
        localization: {}
    };


    $.fn.jkey = function (args) {
        var l18n = defaults.localization;
        // your existing plugin code can use the
        // 'global' localization settings
        console.log(l18n['?']);
        // rest of the plugin...

    };

    $.jkey = function (options) {
         // override the defaults for all plugin calls.
         $.extend(defaults, options)
    }

}(jQuery));
```